# Interpreting p-values of log regressions

Tags: regression, logistic, p-value, interpretation, nonlinear-regression

The following output is for a log log model.

```
Variable       Coefficient Std. Error  t-Statistic  Prob.  


C                11.59474   2.768261    4.188454    0.0002
IN(INCOME)       0.885061   0.174552    5.070475    0.0000
IN(COST)        -0.814077   0.419970   -1.938419    0.0614
IN(POPULATION)   0.455247   0.079531    5.724125    0.0000
IN(DISTANCE_KM) -1.936983   0.284281   -6.813620    0.0000
IN(PERSONS)      0.399901   0.082042    4.874358    0.0000
```

I ran another regression previously which suggested that only Cost and Distance_KM have a non-linear relationship with the dependent variable, Tourist. However, I was wondering whether this model indicates differently, that is, other variables demonstrate a non-linear influence on Tourist or Cost and Distance_KM don't have a non-linear relationship with Tourist.

Also, how to I interpret the p-values on this log-log model?